# Using a Grails 2.4.2 plugin as a JAR dependency in a Grails 2.2.0 project

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, dependency-management, grails-2.2, grails-2.4

I have a custom plugin built using Grails 2.4.2 that is to be used with multiple Grails projects as a regular JAR dependency. I have successfully exported the plugin as JAR and installed into my local Maven repository and added the corresponding dependency statements in the "dependencies" block of the `BuildConfig.groovy` files of the respective parent projects. e.g.:

`compile 'my_package:my_custom_plugin:1.0'`

One of the parent project is build using Grails 2.4.2. When I run that project with the above mentioned configuration using the command: `grails run-app`, it runs fine without any errors.

However, when I do the same kind of configuration in another project built using Grails 2.2.0 and run it using the command: `grails run-app`, it gives the following error:

`Error | Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/datastore/mapping/dirty/checking/DirtyCheckable (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)`

NOTE: Both these parent projects run fine when I add the same plugin as a plugin instead of as a JAR dependency using the statement like this in the `BuildConfig.groovy`:
`grails.plugin.location."my_custom_plugin" = "../my_custom_plugin/"`

Can anybody kindly guide me as to how can I resolve this issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.